# Cartoon children's show with tribal-looking people printing money on leaves with stones

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The series was about a bunch of cartoon characters who looked​ like tribal people.

I remember one episode where the people use barter system (exchange goods for goods), but they come up with the unique plan of printing money using two stones: an imprint on the top stone and pressing it on leaves, giving them crisp money.

But one of the characters changes the imprint to his face in the night and the stones start making money with his face.

This was way before, two decades, most likely a 90's show not sure if it was Nickelodeon, Cbeebies or CN. This was an English cartoon way good in detailing, the people wore nose rings and dresses from leaves.

Comment: The only pre-90's animated show featuring tribal peoples that comes to mind is 'The Mysterious Cities of Gold', though it's been so long since I've watched it (literally decades) I have no clue if a specific episode matches the events you describe.

Comment: No it is not "The Mysterious Cities of Gold", The people actually looked like tribal people with nose rings and not good clothing,  mostly animal skin and leaves

Comment: It sounds like an episode (I never saw them all so I'm guessing) of 'Mike, Lu and Og'

Comment: Thank you @DannyMcG, i was talking about season 2 episode 2 "Money". Thanks for the name..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the cartoon series is *Mike Lu & Og*
and the episode is Season 2 Episode 2.

Mike is a girl from western society who ends up on undeveloped island. Lu and Og are her native friends. Almost every episode is about some invention Mike tries to introduce to the island and improve their lives. Lu is somewhat of an inventor too and helps her by making things she wants to introduce.

They use barter system in season 2 episode 2 and Mike wants to introduce money.